# How to get "calling" Activity instance from called Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a Contact Activity which is derived from ListActivity, which displays
 list of contacts, and on click of item, a new Activity Message Activity derived from
ListActivity is initialized.

Now I know, I can pack some information in Bundle and pass it before creating activity, but
is there a way I can get instance of "ContactActivity" in onCreate method of "MessageActivity"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, sorry, there is no built-in means for you to get at the activity that called `startActivity()` for your current activity. After all, the original activity might not be in your application (e.g., home screen).

Comment: Anyway thanks, the problem is I am unable to move custom objects between activities through Bundle, Bundle only accepts, strings etc, but not business data classes.

Comment: Not true, if you have your data classes implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable` you can pass them with the `Bundle`

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is, you can do a workaround.
In your message Activity declare a static attribute of the type of your contact class, then you set that attribute with the selected contact when the list is clicked and then you start your message activity.
When onCreate is executed in your message activity you can use that attribute.